# Does the RREF need to ALWAYS have at least one non-pivot column?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My feeling is a no. because rref reduces SOE to pivotal rows with leading 1's. Thats the minimum requirement.

Comment: You are correct, just row reduce the $n$ by $n$ diagonal matrix with all $a_{ii}=2$. This is assuming that you are talking about any matrice m. I suggest that you improve your question by providing details. Providing context or background would help also.

Comment: @SinaBabaeiZadeh Why not the simpler example of the identity matrix, which is already in RREF? Anyway, that looks like an answer, so you should really post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there are countless other examples. Just find the reduced row form of any invertible matrix. For instance,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}  $$

has the identity matrix as its RREF form. As mentioned in the comments by user amd, you can even use the identity matrix as a counter example.
(The RREF form of the identity matrix is itself.